# how to handle database reallocation for dotnetnuke website

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, web-config, dotnetnuke

i have a website that used to run on sqlexpress data base i changed my server and it stopped running i ran it using visual studi and IIS but it eith gives me error 404 or error 503 i think the problem is in my webconfig sql string connection her is my code:

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ULTRA; User ID=admin;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
-->
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express -->
    <!--<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ULTRA; User ID=admin;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />--> 
<!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012
-->
<!--<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />--> 

</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules   -->
    <!--<add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />-->
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules
-->
<add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;" />
```

would someone please help me to tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have your connection string defined multiple times in the ConnectionStrings section of the web.config. Which is the proper connection string?

EDIT:
You likely have an issue with the PortalAliases and your IIS configuration. What is the URL that you are trying to access the website using? Make sure that URL is listed in the PortalAliases table, also make sure that IIS will respond to the URL as well.

Comment: the first one, but regardless of any attempts it will not run. my problem is when the site starts running i fell it misplaced what page to start from when ever it runs default it throws this error : "404 Not Found
The requested Url does not return any valid content.
Administrators
Change this message by configuring a specific 404 Error Page or Url for this website." previously this link :localhost:33831 used to display my home page after my database edits this is the link i get: http://localhost/Default.aspx and it always displays that error i am very new to dnn and quite lost here

Comment: Try navigating to /install/install.aspx that should tell you if your connection string is correct. If that page loads an empty (white) page you're good. If it loads an error, it should provide some description for you.

Comment: i ran install.aspx and i got a white page so how can i know what is wrong?

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment